# Siteminder Causing Login Error

Tags: asp.net, siteminder

We are a software dev company company with a product that is deployed at our client's site.  Recently, we started seeing an issue with our login in conjunction with Siteminder.

They have Siteminder turned on but we are not integrating with it for SSO.  They get to our login page just fine.  When a user inputs their login credentials our application returns a login error and does not allow them to login.

Upon further investigation, we found that our login process is receiving 2 different requests!  One with the correct username and PW and another request is blank username and PW.  As soon as we turn Siteminder off, it works correctly.

We are not sure if this is an issue in our code or with Siteminder's setup.  We have other instances of the application that work correctly.  We did no code changes to integrate with SM when we first deployed and it was working fine before.  We sent a code update and then it started not working.  It all points to us but we cannot find it in the code.  Any help here would be great!  We are not sure how SM really works with this.

Comment: Check the SM Policy Server log. My guess is that you are requesting a resource during your login process that is protected by SM. Check trailing slashes ("/")that should or should not be present in your request. Alternatively, the SM policy could have changed.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is not something that Siteminder is causing. Did you trace the JS requests to see if there are two submits being done on the page

Answer (score 0):

Generally WE Disable the **webagent to remove the siteminder component from the infrastructure.** if the end user is able to **access application without the siteminder** component the the **problem relise on siteminder part.**

and if user is **facing an issue while accessing the an application** **without the siteminder composts** . then there is **no issues  on siteminder components.**